# Any way to get internal stored SQLite database using my code?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am trying to access to my early stored `.db` file through my Java code:

```
    String path = "/data/data/" + this.getPackageName() + "/databases/" + DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(path, null);
```

And this is where the `.db` file stored:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKc08.png)

Raw path: `/data/data/com.xxx.xxx/databases/database.db`

But when compiling, Android Studio keeps warning me this: (DATABASE_NAME refers database.db)

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: database.db
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void startMatching() {
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase write = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_ORIGINAL, original);
    
    write.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

**DBHelper.java**

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
public static final Integer DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mTable";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(
            context,
            DATABASE_NAME,
            null,
            DATABASE_VERSION
    );
}
```

I have no idea why this error occurs. Anyone can help? :(

Comment: The error message is: "no such **table**: database.db". Do you use in your code the variable `DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME` as a table's name?

Comment: just pass database name("database") in path , it is in same package why provide full path

Comment: Are you placing the database into the app as an asset (so before compiling the app, are you creating a .db file and then adding it to your project) OR do you want to create a database from within the app?

Comment: @forpas As I said in the question, DATABASE_NAME refers database.db.

Comment: @aryan agarwal Do you mean     SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null);   ?

Comment: Maybe your intention is to use as the database's name. But the error is: *no such table...*. So check your code if you use it incorrectly as a table's name.

Comment: @Zee the latter

Comment: @forpas Thx for you help. I defined DATABASE_NAME in DBHelper like this: public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";  Cannot figure out the problem. :( And I successfully created the db flie like picture in the link.

Comment: You have defined it correctly. My question is where do you use it? Search in your code where it is used. Is it used by mistake where a table's name should be?

Comment: @forpas Thanks for you patient reply. I updated my question.:)

Comment: Is the constructor `DBHelper()` the only place where you use DATABASE_NAME? Check all instances. One of them should be TABLE_NAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android, when you use SqlLiteDatabase, you don't really specify the path. All of this is taken care of for you. Here is some good documentation to follow to get your database started: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

In short, your basic database class will look like:

```
public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

Note how the DB name is JUST a name, NOT a path. you will also have a 'contract' class to define your table constants which you can then use when you create those tables, as well as read/write to and from those tables. Thoroughly read the linked tutorial and you should be good to go!

However, if you want to use a pre-populated database, I suggest you look into SQLiteOpenHelper instead.

Comment: Special thanks to Zee and @forpas ! I confused the TABLE_NAME and DATABASE_NAME, resulting in keep querying non-existing table from my database. It really helped!